# Proving a Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm working through an execrise in *Analysis II* by Terence Tao and I'm stuck.

The aim of the exercise is to prove that the function defined by the infinite series $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{∞}4^{-n}\cos(32^n \pi x)$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, but differentiable nowhere.

I have already shown that $f$ is continuous (the series is uniformly convergent by the Weierstrass $M$-test) and that for all integers $j$ and $m≥1$, $\left| f\left(\frac{j+1}{32^m}\right)- f\left(\frac{j}{32^m} \right) \right| ≥ 4^{-m}$.

It remains to actually prove that $f$ is nowhere differentiable. I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is what I have tried so far:

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. For every $m≥1$, there is an integer $j_m$ such that $j_m≤32^m x_0 ≤ j_m+1$ (this was a hint from the book).

This defines a sequence $x_m = \frac{j_m}{32^m}$ that converges to $x_0$ because $$\left| \frac{j_m}{32^m}-x_0 \right|=x_0-\frac{j_m}{32^m}≤ \frac{1}{32^m}.$$ We get another sequence $y_m=\frac{j_m+1}{32^m}$ also converging to $x_0$ for free.

My idea is to use the two sequences $(x_m)$ and $(y_m)$ to land at a contradiction. For example, as $x_m → x_0$, the derivative (assuming it exists) is:

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{m → ∞}\frac{1}{\frac{j_m}{32^m}-x_0}\sum_{n=1}^{∞}[4^{-n}(\cos(32^{n-m}\pi j_m)-4^{-n}\cos(32^nπx_0)]$$

I can see that the terms $\cos(32^{n-m}πj_m)$ will eventually simplify to $1$ (once $n$ oversteps $m$ strictly). But I had used a similar line of reasoning to prove that $\left| f\left(\frac{j+1}{32^m}\right)- f\left(\frac{j}{32^m} \right) \right| ≥ 4^{-m}$, so I suppose I should use this instead of re-proving something similar.

I'm lost. Any hints?

Note: I know that this a special case of a general classic result, and I have seen a couple proofs on the internet, but they were far too complicated. Regardless, I would like to finish the exercise on my own rather than just see a proof.

Comment: You have that $\left|\frac{f(x_m)-f(y_m)}{x_m-y_m}\right|\geq\frac{32^m}{4^m}$. Add and subtract $f(x_0)$, in the numerator on the left, use triangle inequality and that $|x_m-y_m|\geq\max(|x_m-x_0|,|x_0-y_m|)$

Comment: Thank you! I got it.

Comment: The period of each addend is $\dfrac{1}{32^{n-1}}$ which is fastly decreasing. For $n$ finite, you have "a double saw", still differentiable but not anymore when $n$ is not bounded.

Comment: @NDB Just a suggestion, but your comment did answer my question, so why not post it as an answer?